# Triggering a remote powershell script to run independently

Tags: powershell

I've created a script which calls 'dfsutil', and is available for all the members in my team. Some members don't have RSAT (dfsutil) installed locally, so I'd like to 'trigger' a .ps1 script independently of the source PC (PC1) to be run on a server (Server1) which has 'dfsutil' installed.

It's easy enough to trigger a remote PowerShell script from the source 'PC1' by dot-sourcing it from 'myscript.ps1':

`. \\Server1\scripts\dfsscript.ps1`

As we already know, the above will fail as PowerShell is looking for 'dfsutil' locally on PC1, rather than on the server 'Server1'.

'dfsscript.ps1' has been written so it can be run independently, without need to return the values to PC1.

I can't seem to find any documentation which shows how to initialise a remote script which only uses the values and conditions of the OS it was triggered on.
Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you looked into [Invoke-Command](https://4sysops.com/archives/use-powershell-invoke-command-to-run-scripts-on-remote-computers/)? For example, `Invoke-Command -ComputerName "Server1" -FilePath PC1\scripts\dfsscript.ps1`

Comment: Thanks so much, I've been working on this for a couple of hours, and that didn't even occur to me. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

Dot-sourcing is about the [scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-6) of a PowerShell session, but doesn't include the computing environment, so what you are doing won't get the script on Server1 to run from Server2, but still act like it is on Server1 with access to all of Server1's installed apps, etc.

What you need to do is use PowerShell [remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote?view=powershell-6) to actually run the script on the remote server (i.e. trigger from Server2, but execute on Server1).  For example:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName Server1 -FilePath <path>\script.ps1
```